# use texlive simply on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: latex

I installed Latex on Ubuntu 20.04 using

```
$sudo apt install texlive
```

now I am trying to install a package using

```
$tlmgr install fullpage
```

or

```
$tlmgr --verify-repo=none install fullpage
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2023).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

If local install is 2019 (very old!!), how come it searches to a non corresponding database ?

How come this doesn't work out of the box ? nothing complicated here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The default repository in `tlmgr` is set to `https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet`, which hosts latest `texlive` packages. Since you are using `texlive 2019` you need to change the `tlmgr` repository accordingly.

To check current default repository run

```
tlmgr option repository
```

To change repository to 2019 texlive archive, check [for other repositories](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html#past):

```
tlmgr option repository https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
```

Once repository is changed, you can run [your command[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228902/which-package-should-i-install-to-have-the-fullpage-sty-file)

```
tlmgr install preprint
```

Alternatively you can [install `texlive-latex-extra` package using apt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228920/how-should-i-install-the-fullpage-package-under-ubuntu#answer-255458):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```